# comparing two spark dataframe and generate new third dataframe with remark

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have two spark dataframes, one has 70k rows and the other 60k. I am trying to compare each column string with other dataframe column and generate the new dataframe with Remark condition. If the column string from df1 is present in df2 it will be duplicated remark. I have tried using outer join but, it is not giving me the expected output.

```
df1
colA    colB
A       d4f488bef2
B       c8a91953fc
C       62026fd921
D       e88480226d
E       8335195031

df2
ColA    ColB
W       411c78854c9
X       0bfeb09d6cf
C       62026fd9211
E       8335195031e

**Expected output : df3**
ColA    ColB            Remark
A       d4f488bef2d2    From df1
B       c8a91953fc52    From df1
D       e88480226d3b    From df1
W       411c78854c9c    From df2
X       0bfeb09d6cfb    From df2
C       62026fd921      duplicate(In Both)
E       8335195031      duplicate(In Both)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val df1Remark  = df.withColumn("df1_remark",lit("DF1"))
val df2Remark  = df.withColumn("df2_remark",lit("DF2"))

val res =  df1Remark.join(df1Remark,Seq("colA","colB"),"outer")
                    .withColumn("remark",when(col("df1_remark").isNotNull && col("df2_remark").isNotNull,lit("Duplicate")).otherwise(when(col("df1_remark").isNotNull,lit("From DF1")).otherwise(lit("FROM DF2"))))
```

Comment: @undefined_varable, Thank you for help, It worked for as expected.

Comment: Could you help to join the 35 columns in which 35th column holds the unique match identifier from the two dataframe.   I have tried but not getting duplicate values in remark column.                                                                                                           
` |ColB   |df1_remark|df2_remark|Remark  |
+--------------------------------+-----+
|830357f|null      |DF2       |FROM DF2|
|830357f|DF1       |null      |From DF1|  `

Comment: check your join clause.. in the above comment df1_remark is null.. that means record is from `df2`.. so either you have used wrong column in join condition.. or data is missing in df2

Comment: Below is the code I used for join,                                                                          ``` val res = df1.join(df2,Seq("colA","colB","colC","colD","colE","colF","colG","colH","colI","colJ","colK","colL","colM","uniq"),"outer")

|uniq    |colA   |colB   |df1_remark|df2_remark|
+--------+-------+-------+----------+----------+
|76cdbfb1|2019-11|2019-11|DF1       |null      |
|76cdbfb1|2019-11|2019-11|null      |DF2       | ```                                               
 can you please help if any modification required in code

Comment: This join will perform the join with in columns. I want the output in rows(vertically) as per the expected output from the main question.  The df2 data should append on df1 as per the join condition.                                                 
``` df1.join(df2, df1("uniq") === df2("uniq"), "outer")

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with [spark-extension](https://github.com/G-Research/spark-extension) and three simple lines:

```
import uk.co.gresearch.spark.diff._

val opts = DiffOptions("Remarks", "df1", "df2", "From df2", "changed", "From df1", "duplicate(In Both)")

df1.diff(df2, opts).show

+------------------+----+-----------+
|           Remarks|colA|       colB|
+------------------+----+-----------+
|          From df2|   X|0bfeb09d6cf|
|          From df1|   B| c8a91953fc|
|duplicate(In Both)|   E|8335195031e|
|          From df1|   A| d4f488bef2|
|          From df1|   D| e88480226d|
|duplicate(In Both)|   C|62026fd9211|
|          From df2|   W|411c78854c9|
+------------------+----+-----------+
```

The `diff` transformation computes the difference between `df1` and `df2`, and the `opts: DiffOptions` formats the output in the format you defined in your question.

The default output format would look like this:

```
df1.diff(df2).show
+----+----+-----------+
|diff|colA|       colB|
+----+----+-----------+
|   I|   X|0bfeb09d6cf|
|   D|   B| c8a91953fc|
|   N|   E|8335195031e|
|   D|   A| d4f488bef2|
|   D|   D| e88480226d|
|   N|   C|62026fd9211|
|   I|   W|411c78854c9|
+----+----+-----------+
```

Comment: Hi @Enri , I am getting the error `Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.uk.co.gresearch.spark.diff.DiffOptions.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/StringOps$`  while executing the statement `df1.diff(df2).show`. Please help. Have spent many hours with no fruitful result

Comment: Support is provided at https://github.com/G-Research/spark-extension/issues.